# Encode the data into parent/children json data format

Tags: javascript

I have the json data like this.

```
 var data=    [
{"categoryName":"VPN", "INCIDENT_ID":"IN006336", "DESCRIPTION":"vpn not complaint",    
"maximumHit":"2"},


{"categoryName":"VPN", "INCIDENT_ID":"IN006112", "DESCRIPTION":"VPN issues asked to   
reinstall vpn client", "maximumHit":"2"}, 


{"categoryName":"VPN", "INCIDENT_ID":"IN011902", "DESCRIPTION":"vpn installation link- 
itldrive", "maximumHit":"2"}];
```

and want data in the following format

```
 var json2 =
   {
         "name": "Network Issue",
         "children": [
          {
           "name": "DESCRIPTION", 
           "children": 

            [
              {"name": "vpn not complaint"},
              {"name": "VPN issues asked to reinstall vpn client"},
              {"name": "vpn installation link- itldrive"}
             ]
          },

          {
           "name": "INCIDENT_ID",
           "children": [

            {"name": "IN006336"},
            {"name": "IN006112"},
                {"name": "IN006112"}
           ]
          },

          {
           "name": "categoryName",
           "children": [
               {"name": "VPN"},
            {"name": "VPN"},
                {"name": "VPN"}
           ]
          }
         ]
        }
```

Comment: Both of your code snippets show JS objects and arrays, **not** JSON. Do you really want JSON or just change your data structure?

Comment: i want json for making collapsible tree in D3. So i need to convert the data into tree/node structured json

Comment: If you are working with D3, then I think you actually want a JS array or object. JSON is a textual data-exchange format, like XML or CSV. It might be that you load your data as JSON from the server, but when you process it with JavaScript, you are working with arrays and objects.

Comment: yes i want an json array of objects.

Comment: I think you still haven't understood the distinction between JavaScript arrays/objects and JSON. Please have a look at this link: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/.

Comment: I want to change data structure of JS objects and arrays.Kindly provide me that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
var str = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2);
```